# Sort after sort while keeping first sort?

Tags: bash, sorting, unix, vim

So I use sort to sort it via my first columm in vim.

```
apple bear
apple zoo
apple bar
banana hockey
banana football
```

But then, I want it to sort it on the second column, that it becomes this:

```
apple bar
apple bear
apple zoo
banana football
banana hockey
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this in vim?

Comment: @shellter you may want to take a read of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25925/253425

Comment: I don't get it. For your given in- and output, just use sort once and be done with it?! A different matter if you want to change sortorder for the first and second column but I can't make that up from you question.

Answer (score 0):

First move to the start of the file:

```
gg
```

Then use 'sort -k 2' to sort the buffer:

```
!Gsort -k 2<ENTER>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me, using Vim's built in sort function:

```
:sort! r/ /|sort
```

This works even if not sorted to begin with.